# Нужно получить все комбинации слов

Tags: javascript, массивы, комбинаторика, перебор

Есть текст из нескольких слов, нужно перебрать каждое сочетание этих слов через запятую в одну строчку. Так как таких фраз для перебора около тысячи.

- **Исходная фраза может состоять из разного количества слов!(Исходная фраза может состоять как из 2 слов так и из 5)**.
- **Порядок слов в комбинациях тоже должен учитываться! (то есть кошка собака != собака кошка).**
- **Перебор должен состоять по принципу abc => abc, ab, ba, ac,

  ca, acb, bca, a, b, c и так далее.**

Приветствуются варианты разрешения данной проблемы на любом языке программирования (JS в приоритете). Если вариант возможет в Эксель формулами, будет только лучше. За правильное решение готов отблагодарить денюжкой на карту.
Пример в коде:

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

p {
  text-wrap: wrap
}

* {
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Исходная фраза:</h1>
  <p>кошка собака дом</p>
  <h1>Результативная фраза:</h1>
  <p>Кошка собака дом, кошка дом собака, кошка дом, кошка собака, кошка, собака кошка, собака дом, собака, собака дом кошка, собака кошка дом, дом, дом собака, дом кошка, дом собака кошка, дом кошка собака</p>
</div>
```

Comment: И что вызвало проблему? Невозможность разбития исходной фразы на слова и занесения их в массив? Или составление комбинаций из  элементов массива?

Comment: составления комбинаций

Comment: @Grandeamore Повторяющиеся слова в исходной фразе будут присутствовать? Если да, что с ними должно произойти на выходе, должны остаться все или должно остаться одно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример рекурсивной генерации на Python. Функция берёт текущую комбинацию, и вставляет в неё очередной элемент (с номером idx) во все возможные места, а также пропускает данный элемент (второй вызов gencomb)

```
def gencombs(comb, lst, idx):
    if idx >= len(lst):
        print(comb)
    else:
        for i in range(len(comb),-1, -1):
            gencombs(comb[:i] + [lst[idx]] + comb[i:], lst, idx + 1)
        gencombs(comb, lst, idx + 1)

gencombs([],"abc", 0)

['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['c', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'b']
['b', 'a', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'a']
['c', 'b', 'a']
['b', 'a']
['a', 'c']
['c', 'a']
['a']
['b', 'c']
['c', 'b']
['b']
['c']
[]
```

Comment: Совершенно не понятно как это работает, но очевидно - работает! Как впервые `comb` получает не пустое значение особенно  интересно.

Comment: @Leonid Самое первое не пустое - это [a]. На следующем уровне b может добавиться после а, до а, или вообще не добавиться. В первом случае имеем [a,b], и на следующем уровне рекурсии вставляем с в три места, получая [a,b,c], [a,c,b] и [c,a,b], а также [a,b] без c.

Comment: `range(len(comb),-1, -1)` здесь же вроде `len(comb)` равен нулю и итерация никогда не начнется? Что я не так понимаю?

Comment: Начнется, единственная итерация со значением i=0. Нижнее ограничение range ведь -1, и шаг отрицательный. Если переделать на положительный шаг, то будет `range(len(comb)+1) = range(1)`

Comment: Вы спасли меня! Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = 'кошка, собака, дом';

function genaCrocodile(str) {
  let arr = str.split(', ');
  let set = new Set();

  for (let i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
      let randomArr = arr.slice(0).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

      if (i !== arr.length) {
        randomArr.length = i;
      }

      set.add(randomArr.join(' '));
    }
  }

  return [...set].join(', ');
}

console.log(genaCrocodile(str));
```

Comment: Что-то прям тяжеловато идет, а если значительно больше значений?

Comment: @Leonid Да, тепловоз немного, но за полчаса времени только такое слепилось. Это же не решение под ключ за гонорар, это чисто рабочий пример, который может подсказать как можно было решить задачу. Обычно, людям именно подсказка нужна, а дальше сами допиливают.